# Xcode 7 auto generate initialization, getter and setter?

Tags: xcode, getter, getter-setter

Hi I used to develop android app with android studio. I now building my app for IOS using Xcode 7. Is there any way or any framework that do the `initialization`, `getter` and `setter`, `parcelable` for model `class` (like `android studio` have automatic generate). Can `Xcode` do the same and how to do that automatically? (just declare the variable and auto generate `initialization`, `getter`, `setter`...)

Comment: You don't actually need getter and setter, anything declared as property without **read only** option, can be directly set, or get by **className.propertyName**. XCode don't have this feature.

Comment: thanks for your respond. Can explain a bit in detail? sometime we need also need to pass data between view also (for example passing user data...) and the initialization (construction) of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler provides basic getter and setter according to the property declaration. If those don't fit your needs, you have to write them yourself.

Let's say you have this property:

```
property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myValue;
```

The setter has to have this signature:

```
- (void)setMyValue(value: String) {
    // some stuff
    _myValue = value;
}
```

The getter has to have this signature:

```
- (NSString *)myValue {
    // some other stuff
    return _myValue;
}
```

Comment: i'm writing in swift. how to call the basic getter and setter in Xcode (initialization also)? in android studio there an alt+insert to auto generate construction, getter, setter... Is there a similar way to do that in Xcode?

Comment: No, there isn't. You have to write that yourself. You might have a look in the Swift book by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you have a recommend way to quickly type those or just remember, copy and paste?

Comment: I remember those. But I use them rarely.

Comment: What do u mean by rare use? I thought we have to use for every model class?

Comment: Most of the times I use the setter and getter generated by the compiler.

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh There's no need to generate getters and setters in Swift. Default initializers are also there, but you'll have to add your own persistence support. Please read the Swift documentation for more information.